# how to check column structure in ssis?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a table customer in my sql server.

**Columns**

1. Distributer_Code
2. Cust_code
3. cust_name
4. cust_add
5. zip
6. tel
7. dl_number
8. gstin

we receive customer files from the distributor on a monthly basis.
so sometimes they send files with the wrong structuer.. like maybe gstin is missing or dl_number is missing or gstin is in place of dl_number and dl_number is in place of tel...basically, columns could be split..

when we upload those flat files with SSIS it gives error..and data doesn't get uploaded on the server if the structure is wrong.

I want to upload those data with null data if columns are missing or columns are misplaced.

[image: Data Flow in SSIS]

Comment: "we receive customer files" - What kind of files? Do the files have an indication on what values they provide?

Comment: The files are flat files separated by a pipe " | " delimiter

Comment: Do you have any kind of indication inside the file itself on what columns are missing? can a single file contain multiple rows with different columns missing for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Based on your comment, you are handling with flat files. To solve this problem, you have to read all columns as one column and retrieve the structure on the go.

## Details

1. First add a Flat file connection manager.
2. In the flat file connection manager, go to the Advanced Tab, remove all columns and keep only one column *(Column0)*.
3. Change the column type to DT_WSTR and the length to 4000.
4. Add a `Dataflow task`
5. Inside the `Dataflow task` add a Flat File source, a script component and an OLEDB destination.
6. Open the script component, go to Input/Output Tab and and add 8 output columns *(Distributer_Code,Cust_code,cust_name,cust_add,zip,tel,dl_number,gstin)*
7. Change the script language to Visual Basic.
8. Inside the script write the following code.

   ```
   Dim Distributer_Code as integer = -1
   Dim Cust_code as integer = -1
   Dim cust_name as integer = -1
   Dim cust_add as integer = -1
   Dim zip as integer = -1
   Dim tel as integer = -1
   Dim dl_number as integer = -1
   Dim gstin as integer = -1
   Dim intRowIndex as integer = 0

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       If intRowIndex = 0 then

           Dim strfields() as string = Row.Column0.split(CChar("|"))
           Dim idx as integer = 0

           For idx = 0 To strFields.length - 1

               Select case str

               Case "Distributer_Code"
                   Distributer_Code = idx  
               Case "Cust_code"
                   Cust_code = idx 
               Case "cust_name"
                   cust_name = idx 
               Case "cust_add"
                   cust_add = idx  
               Case "zip"
                   zip = idx   
               Case "tel"
                   tel = idx   
               Case "dl_number"
                   dl_number = idx 
               Case "gstin"
                   gstin = idx 

               End Select

           Next

       Else

           Dim strfields() as string = Row.Column0.split(CChar("|"))

           If Distributer_Code > -1 Then Row.DistributerCode = strfields(Distributer_Code)
           If Cust_code > -1 Then Row.Custcode = strfields(Cust_code)
           If cust_name > -1 Then Row.custname = strfields(cust_name)
           If cust_add > -1 Then Row.custadd = strfields(cust_add)
           If zip > -1 Then Row.zip = strfields(zip)
           If tel > -1 Then Row.tel = strfields(tel)
           If dl_number > -1 Then Row.dlnumber = strfields(dl_number)
           If gstin > -1 Then Row.gstin = strfields(gstin)

       End If


       intRowIndex += 1

   End Sub
   ```
9. Map the output columns to the OLEDB Destination

Comment: If the column isn't found, what will the constant be? i.e. if there's no `cust_add` column, what is the value of the `cust_add` variable and therefore the value in the row?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you're right! The code must be improved. I will do that tonight. Thanks

Comment: Great answer BTW I would never have considered doing it this way